# PostgreSQL installation with existing Ruby on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, pg

I am on Mac OSX lion and am new to Ruby on Rails programming, so bear with me.

I'm trying to work on a teammates' Ruby on Rails app, but it requires that I have PostgreSQL installed. I installed it with Postgres.app (version 9.2.2). However, when I run rails server, I get the following error.

```
/Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': dlopen(/Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/pg-0.14.1/lib/pg_ext.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/pg-0.14.1/lib/pg_ext.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/pg-0.14.1/lib/pg_ext.bundle
from /Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
from /Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/pg-0.14.1/lib/pg.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
from /Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
from /Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
from /Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
from /Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
from /Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `require'
from /Users/kevin/Documents/photowhoa/config/application.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
from /Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
from /Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I've already tried uninstalling and reinstalling the PG gem. If anyone can help me, that would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: I don't know anything about Postgres.app, but I'd personally go the Homebrew route instead. I've had success with that multiple times.

Comment: Are you sure that the PG gem installed okay?  Doesn't look like it did... confirm that's installed correctly first... I have a laptop with a similar setup (using the postgres app) and it works just fine.

Comment: You might find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182645/ruby-on-rails-postgresql-library-not-loaded-error-when-starting-server-libq

Answer (score 1):

Same problem. Rake can't find Postgres library.
This fixes the problem:

> export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/lib

Adjust path to lib to match yours.