# Rails 4.2.5 PostgreSQL "Library not loaded: libz.1.2.6.dylib"

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have old RoR applications working fine with Postgresql 9.1, on my Mac with  Ruby 2.0.0 and Rails 4.0.2

Now I have to do another project and I want to use latest ruby and rails version:

**=> ruby-2.2.3@4.2.5 [ x86_64 ]**

I can install pg gem without problems I have in `config` file (insdide `.bundle`) this

```
BUNDLE_BUILD__PG: --with-pg-config=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin/pg_config
```

Bu when I run "rake db:create" or "rails s" I get this error:

```
LoadError: dlopen(/Users/albertcatalacasulleras/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@4.2.5/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0-static/pg-0.18.4/pg_ext.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: libz.1.2.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/albertcatalacasulleras/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@4.2.5/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0-static/pg-0.18.4/pg_ext.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/albertcatalacasulleras/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@4.2.5/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0-static/pg-0.18.4/pg_ext.bundle
```

I think there is something in Rails 4.2.5 or in Ruby 2.2.3 that makes this crash.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [this answare](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15512644/547341) of Craig Ringer I found the solution:

Adding `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/library/PostgreSQL/9.1/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`
 to .bash_rofile file

another issue it would be having two PstgreSQL databases 9.1 and 9.4, por example...

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same type of issue and it is solved for me by uninstalling the pg gem and install it again with the options as like below.

```
sudo gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin/pg_config
```

Search for the pg_config file in the installation path of you postgres app and give that path as shown above.

Please refer the following url for more details.

[Github url link](https://github.com/PostgresApp/PostgresApp/issues/83#issuecomment-15163862)